# Transforming a geometric form: from a linear form to a sine wave

Tags: matrix, graphics3d

[image: 3D Graphic Tube in ascending spiral]
[image: Stack of 3D Graphic Tubes]

I want to transform the stack of ascending spiral tubes in the second picture into a sine wave of spiral tubes. The sine wave would progress in the independent variable sense along the X axis and in the dependent variable sense in the Z axis direction.

I have looked at both graphic transforms such as GeometricTransformation and transformations such as RotationTransforms of the data, that is used to generate the geometric Tube. It is important that the Tubes mesh from one level to the next in the stack. My attempts to use the Sin[] and Cos [] functions in the transformation have not produced the meshed Tubes that I need.

Ideally, I would build a linear stack of ascending spirals as in Picture 2 and GeometricTransform the geometric object into a Sine Wave shape. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Forgive me if I have missed something very obvious. I don't have a lot of experience with Mathematica

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code about the two pictures.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.